# Pepper - nested animations possible?

Tags: android, animation, nested, pepper

We recently purchased an Android-based Pepper and i'm slowing discovering its capabilities (and limitations).

I was wondering if it's possible to run two animations at the same time - one animation trajectory and another animation timeline (e.g. to have Pepper move forward one meter and have it raise it's arms at the same time)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can call `AnimationBuilder.withResources` several times: once with a timeline, and once with a trajectory.

```
Animation myAnimation = AnimationBuilder.with(qiContext)
                                        .withResources(R.raw.bodyAnimationResource)
                                        .withResources(R.raw.trajectoryResource)
                                        .build();
```

But if I'm wrong, at least I'm sure that [AnimationBuilder.withResources](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/qisdk/index.html?com/) accepts an array.

Note that if you combine two animations moving the same joints, it will not work.

Comment: amazing, thanks Victor, i hadn't thought of that - will test tomorrow and let you know. many thanks!

Comment: i tried your suggestion out today and it works like a charm - many thanks Victor!